# Calling javascript functions on pageload not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code I am using at the bottom of my javascript (just to test) in order to get my functions working on page load:

```
// Call to load     
$(document).ready(function()
{
    test();
}​
```

At the top of my javascript file I have this:

```
function test() {
alert("hello")
};
```

Why isnt my test being called?

Comment: there's a typo but in the first func - you should close like `test();})`

Comment: Just want to mention that in JS very often you would prefer to do your testing with `console.log()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look closer at your jQuery call:

```
// Call to load     
$(document).ready(function()
{
    test();
}​
```

You're missing the end ) and a semicolon.

```
// Call to load     
$(document).ready(function()
{
    test();
}​);
```

You could tell this if you checked the console in your browser.

Answer (score 4):

There's a typo(you missed one bracket):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    test();
}​);
```

Comment: You'll throw an error with that function call. It has one too many )